# How do I implement a breakdown into server pages?

Tags: angular

It is necessary to make a pagination by a connected server. [Here](http://michaelbromley.github.io/ngx-pagination/#/server-paging) is an example of this breakdown into server pages. But I have already lost an hour and do not understand how to do it. Currently only the first 10 records are displayed.

Pagination is not displayed. Can someone explain how to do this?

**sevice:**

```
page: number = 1;

getPosts(page?: number): Observable<Post[]>{
    return this._authService.get(`posts?page=${page}`)
    .map((res: Response) => <Post[]>res.json())
        .do(res => {
            this.page = page;
        })
}
```

**ts:**

```
  page: number;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPosts(this.page);
  }

  getPosts(page: number) {
    this.page = page;
    this.servPost.getPosts(page).subscribe(
      (data: Post[]) => {
        this.posts = data; 
    });
  }
```

**html:**

```
<div *ngFor="let post of posts?.data 
| paginate: {itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage:page, id: 'server',  totalItems:posts?.count }"> 
....
</div>
<div class="pagination-block " style="justify-content: center">
  <pagination-controls (pageChange)="getPosts($event)" id="server">
  </pagination-controls>
</div>
```

Here's what my **JSON** looks like:

```
{
  "data":[
               {"id":234,"name":"Text","raw_rnum_":1},
               {"id":341,"name":"Text2","raw_rnum_":2},
               {"id":347,"name":"Text3","raw_rnum_":3},
               {"id":435,"name":"Text4","raw_rnum_":4},
               {"id":456,"name":"Text5","raw_rnum_":5},
               {"id":523,"name":"Text6","raw_rnum_":6},
               {"id":578,"name":"Text7","raw_rnum_":7},
               {"id":592,"name":"Tex8","raw_rnum_":8},
               {"id":673,"name":"Text9","raw_rnum_":9},
               {"id":690,"name":"Text10","raw_rnum_":10}
             ],
  "meta":{"total":3242}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You bind wrong value on `totalItems` pipe, try to change your code as like below,

`totalItems:posts.meta.total`

Comment: Are you getting this (`"meta":{"total":3242}`) value in your JSON response  ?

Comment: All thanks, it came to me how to do it  It was necessary to add a "?" `totalItems:posts?.meta.total`